# Visual Studio Codelens for methods invoked by reflection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, method-reference, codelens

Codelens in Visual Studio is great, but I've inherited a code base where some methods are invoked via reflection.

This is a simplified sample.

```
...
if (method.Name.EndsWith("UpdatePlatformModel");
     method.Invoke(element, parameters)
...
```

[image]

In the attached image, the codelens states the method has 0 (zero) references. I understand that since this is invoked at runtime, the reference number won't reflect the number of times the method is called.

Is there a way via Visual Studio, a third party plugin, or any other strategy, where I can analyze the code to identify if a method is referenced or not?

Comment: C# calls methods through reflection. "method.Invoke(element, parameters)". You can run it in the main method.

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT, can you elaborate a bit further to make sure I fully understand your response? Thanks